# In Flutter, how can I make sure that ChangNotifier is not being used before running the state dispose?

Tags: flutter, listener, dispose

I'm getting the following error with `ChangeNotifier.dispose`.

```
A ShakeWidgetState was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a ShakeWidgetState, it can no longer be used.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      ChangeNotifier.dispose (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:302:27)
```

I did some research but none of the possible solutions works for me. I even comment out the `notifyListeners` but the error is still thrown. Here is the snippet of my code.

```
class ShakeWidgetState extends State<ShakeWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, ChangeNotifier {
bool disposed=false;
@override
  void notifyListeners() {
    if (!disposed) {
      super.notifyListeners();
    }
  }
void dispose() {
     // assert(ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed(this));
    _disposed = true;
       super. Dispose();
    //});
  }
}
```

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: the issue occured because you initialize the `ChangeNotifier` as local state. and disposed from the tree widget.

Comment: @pmatatis. Thanks for pointing it out but how should I fix it?